# Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript doesn't work - why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, registerstartupscript

i have some code in OnInit hanlder

```
if (!Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered(GetType(), "MyScript"))
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "MyScript", GetStartupScript(), true);
}
```

here i try to register some java script code. and i want it to work on button click event. but it doesn't execute. it executes only after refreshing page. can anyone explain me why it doesn't execute?

thnx in advance!

Comment: Might be related to Page Life Cycle events. You may look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "Error", 
    "alert('hi');", true);
```

The issue is that on some pages you might have declared a `ScriptManager`. Only one `ScriptManager` is allowed per page so you have to use the existing `ScriptManager` to register any scripts.

Note that the `RegisterStartupScript` is a static method; do not call it on the instance of your `ScriptManager` (it will cause a compile error in C# but only a warning in VB.NET).

[This](https://codewala.net/2011/11/24/page-clientscript-registerstartupscript-is-not-working/) link has a bit more info on this issue.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  If you want a short but good explanation, check [this link out.](http://codewala.net/2011/11/24/page-clientscript-registerstartupscript-is-not-working/)

Answer (score 2):

```
 string msg = "This is variable message";
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "well1", "<script>alert('" + msg + "');</script>");
```

Answer (score -4):

this worked fine for me :

```
Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('" + AlerteMsg + "');</script>");
```

Comment: Please, for the sake of everything holy. Tell us you were not serious.